# How to implement clickable listview and show list details in different fragment layout?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I've managed to develop list view.I don't know how to make it clickable and show the clicked list details in different layout pages. Give me a solution to achieve this.
here is my **MainActivity.java**

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.app.Activity;



    public class ActivityList extends Activity {
        ListView list;
        String[] web = {
                "Design",
                "Centers",
                "Products",
                "Search",
                "Clients",
                "About Us"

        } ;
        Integer[] imageId = {
                R.drawable.ic_sws,
                R.drawable.ic_centers,
                R.drawable.ic_pc,
                R.drawable.ic_fmc,
                R.drawable.ic_person,
                R.drawable.ic_bhs,

        };
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.homelist);
            CustomList adapter = new CustomList(ActivityList.this, web, imageId);
            list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                   Toast.makeText(ActivityList.this, "You Clicked at " + web[+position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

    });
        }
    }
```

Here is **CustomList.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] web;
    private final Integer[] imageId;
    public CustomList(Activity context,
                      String[] web, Integer[] imageId) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_single, web);
        this.context = context;
        this.web = web;
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        txtTitle.setText(web[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Hers is **homelist.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

here is **list_single.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TableRow>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="12dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textAlignment="viewEnd"

            />


    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Making a view clickable is easy as follows;

```
yourView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //Do something here

        }
    });
```

In your case, you can make your imageViews and textViews clickable. Or, you may wrap them in a button and make them completely clickable. Since in your custom list adapter, you have the position parameter, you can access the related list item's info.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am new to Android.Could you please explain in detail and add setOnClickListener in my code.

Comment: For that, I need what you want to display when you click on a item. You have only strings list and no further information. What will be displayed?

Comment: By the way, your code already has clickable items and their names appear at the click, isn't i what you wanted?

Comment: The Display content will be different for different items.I want to display some information and image for that particular item. It may require to use different layouts according to type of item.

Comment: Yes..When I click on the item.It has to display the content in different xml page.I dont want to use same xml page for all items since there are different type of items.

Comment: OK got it, wait I'll write a new answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main methods if you want to display the information in another layout. First one is using a dialog box with your custom layout, and the second one is starting a new activity passing the required parameters. Here are details;

1- Custom Dialog Box;

You can create a default dialog box and display info. But if you want further layout style, you shoulld use custom dialog box. For that, you need to first create an XML file. In your case, you may want an ImageView and a TextView like this;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text" />
```

Then you have to create a dialog box, customize it's layout, and pass the related parameters. You can all do this in your list's onItemClickListener. The `arg2` parameter is the position you click in the list. So add this code inside the listener instead of toast;

```
    Dialog dialogBox= new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialogBox.setContentView(R.layout.custom_layout);
    dialogBox.setTitle("Info");
    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setText(web[arg2]);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setImageResource(imageId[arg2]);
    dialogBox.show();
```

2- Start a New Activity

You have to create a new activity and layout, and pass parameters. You can simply use the same layout above, and add the activity as follows;

```
public class Info extends ActionBarActivity {
ImageView imageView;
TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_layout);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
}

}
```

Here the main trick comes. In your list item's listener, you have to create Intent, pass Bundle, then start this activity. And in the activty, you have to obtan the Bundle, and set Views accordingly. Step by step, you can create an intent, pass bundle and create the activity as follows;

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Info.class);
            Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();

            mBundle.putInt("img", imageId[arg2]);
            mBundle.putInt("txt", web[arg2]);
            mIntent.putExtras(mBundle);

            startActivity(mIntent);
```

But be careful, you must modify this activity to obtain the bunde and set the Views before you run above code. In Info activity we created, there are an imageView and textView. You obtain the bundle values as follows;

```
String text = (String) getIntent().getExtras("txt");
int resId= (int) getIntent().getExtras("img");
```

Then you just have to set these resources to the Views;

```
textView.setText(text);
imageView.setImageResource(resId);
```

That's it!! Now you can safely start this activity. Hope you have got the main logic.